# Converting json String to UTF-8

Tags: android, json, unicode, utf-8

I'm parsing data from web in json in gujarati language but when i receive it at android application it looks like

```
{"message":"Authorized","u_status":0,"c_Alert":0,"get_data":[{"id":"29","End":"2015-02-19","EntrTime":"2015-02-26","Content":"&#2733;&#2736;&#2724;&#2752;&#2728;&#2753;&#2690; &#2744;&#2765;&#2725;&#2739; - &#2744;&#2750;&#2732;&#2736; &#2744;&#2765;&#2730;&#2763;&#2736;&#2765;&#2719;&#2765;&#2744; &#2744;&#2765;&#2719;&#2759;&#2721;&#2751;&#2735;&#2734; , &#2745;&#2751;&#2690;&","Begin":"2015-03-10","Header":"&#2738;&#2742;&#2765;&#2709;&#2736;&#2752; &#2733;&#2736;&#2724;&#2752; &#2734;&#2759;&#2739;&#2763; - &#2745;&#2751;&#2690;&#2734;&#2724;&#2728;&#2711;&#2736;","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com"}],"c_Alert_Msg":"No Message","u_link":"http:\/\/www.google.com","c_Alert_Finish":0,"success":1}
```

when i set any filtered text from json string it looks like

```
&#274 4;&#276 5;&#272 5;&#273 9;
```

(i putted space because it shows perfect unicode in html code)
but actually it is

"સ્થળ"

I know thats encoding problem but how did i convert that strings to proper unicode characters

I'm using following code for http request to get json

```
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_for_is);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
               Log.d("JSON 123123",obj.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I also tried getting string from json and converting perticular string to unicode but no effect

by this

```
  JSONObject c = contenTs.getJSONObject(1);
  String headN = c.getString("Header");

  Charset chrutf = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
  final String b = new String(headN.getBytes(),chrutf);
  System.out.println(b);
```

or tell me the way that i can convert characters like '&#274 4;&#276 5;&#272 5;&#273 9;' to unicode string

Comment: Did you tried to convert the result before inserting it into the JSONObject?

Comment: mean what to convert ?

Comment: `String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);`

Comment: @3d0 No effect string is stil as it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really bad that my post given negative reputation because they don't know the answer but i found the solution myself

I simply converted text to html content in code and displayed it using

```
String contentN = json.getJSONArray("get_data").getJSONObject(i).getString("c_Alert_Msg");
Html.fromHtml(contentN))
```

full code

```
 contenTs = json.getJSONArray("get_data");
 itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

 for (int i = 0; i < contenTs.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = contenTs.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString("id");
            String headN = c.getString("Header");
            String contentN = c.getString("Content");
            String time_s = c.getString("Begin");
            String time_e = c.getString("End");
            String linkIn = c.getString("link");

            HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Spannable>();
            String txtHeadN = "<font color=#cc0029><strong>" + String.valueOf(i + 1) + " - " + headN + "</font>";
            map.put("head", Html.fromHtml(txtHeadN));
            map.put("content",Html.fromHtml(contentN));
            map.put("Link", time_s + "  to  " + time_e);
            map.put("links",linkIn);
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            itemList.add(map);
  }
```

And it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Maybe like this:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Or, have you tried encoding your entity using library Gson ?

You can include it like this in your *build.gradle (Module: app)*:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
}
```

and then use this part of code:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(params), HTTP.UTF_8)));
```

Hope it helps.

Lionel

Comment: no I've seen that gson is deprecated and I have not much idea about it so I use just personalized code for json response

Comment: I edited my post: using new StringEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params), HTTP.UTF_8) maybe?

Comment: new StringEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params) not works because 'StringEntity(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' in 'org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity' cannot be applied to '(org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity, java.lang.String)'

Comment: I think i have found:
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`String jsonText = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);`

Comment: Nopp i don't know what problem is i used your code too but still no effect

Answer (score 0):

```
// Java will convert it into a UTF-16 representation 
String s = “This is my string” ; 
 
// byte representation in UTF-8 
ByteBuffer byteBuff = StandardCharset.UTF-8.encode(s); 
 
// do what you want with this byte buffer 
String v = new String( bytes, StandardCharset.UTF-8 );
```