# How to convert a string to UTF-8 for decoding with jSON?

Tags: java, android, json

I need to convert a string to UTF-8(Bangla) I am making an android app with FCM.
 I am using this code to send the data.
I am using a html from to do this and there is two fildes.

```
     $title = $_POST['title'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $image_url =  $_POST['img'];

     public function setTitle($title) {
    $this->title = $title;
}

public function setMessage($message) {
    $this->message = $message;
}

public function setImage($imageUrl) {
    $this->image = $imageUrl;
}


public function setIsBackground($is_background) {
    $this->is_background = $is_background;
}

   public function getPush() {
    $res = array();
    $res['data']['title'] = $this->title;
    $res['data']['is_background'] = $this->is_background;
    $res['data']['message'] = $this->message;
    $res['data']['image'] = $this->image;


    $res['data']['timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    return $res;
}   
          $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
         'charset=UTF-8'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
```

**Java code for my app:**

```
    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    System.out.println("Data Message: "+json);

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String ptitle = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        String title = URLDecoder.decode(ptitle, "utf-8");



        //Send notification data to MessageShowActivity class for showing
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageShowActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        resultIntent.putExtra("timestamp", timestamp);
        resultIntent.putExtra("image", imageUrl);



            showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("in 1st CATCH");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("in 2nd CATCH");
    }
}

private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}
```

When I write in UTF-8(Bangla) only message text shows it, But title are like the ones in the picture below.

***Any guidance would be deeply appreciated!***

[image: see]

Comment: and this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750729/converting-json-string-to-utf-8

Comment: You used a URLDecoder, which decodes to only values valid inside a URL

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20393193/8143436

Comment: @MaheshVayak That's already done

Comment: Please edit question to show actual JSON content and what `data.getString("title")` is on its own

Comment: @cricket_007 done

Comment: I didn't want the PHP, I just wanted the actual JSON. Please log it in the app

Comment: oh. It's same look like picture above

Comment: fix the problem i just use this  "String title = Html.fromHtml(ptitle).toString();" Thank you